# Why does AGP-FRA-HOG not appear in flight searches?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

I want to travel from Málaga, Spain (AGP) to Holguín, Cuba (HOG) around January or February 2023 (this is a follow-up of [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174167/flight-agp-hog-in-a-single-ticket) question). Both Google Flights and ITA Matrix offer combinations with final leg from Toronto by Air Canada. However there is a shorter and cheaper itinerary with a single stop at FRA, with the added benefit of not requiring visa (I am a Schengen citizen).

For instance:

1. 21/1/23   Lufthansa 1149
2. 22/1/23   Condor 2206
3. 29/1/23   Condor 2207
4. 30/1/23   Lufthansa 1148

Why does this combination not appear in search engines? It cannot be booked on a single ticket (at least on the web) and it requires one overnight layover, but so do some results that appear. Only when I use the multi-city option can I get this result.

As a bonus question, could a travel agent book this itinerary on a single ticket? (It is intriguing that Condor does offer Havana or Varadero on a single ticket including a leg from LH, but not Holguin)

EDIT: [This](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8050/are-some-airline-routings-unbookable) has been suggested as duplicate. It certainly has an overlap, but the OP specifically mentions they want a single ticket, which I am resigned to dispense with. Also the agreement from Condor to LH exists for Cuba destinations, given the cases of Havana and Varadero. What intrigues me is why the search does not give the itinerary even as separate tickets.

Comment: Rhetorical question: Why do you want a single ticket? You want that the airlines share responsibility (and costs) in case of missing connection, but this has a cost which airlines may not want to think of (because lack of demand, or agreement with other airlines)

Comment: In addition to the fares to Havana & Varadero you found, it also appears that Condor will sell you a MAD–FRA–HOG itinerary via their website, with the MAD–FRA leg on Lufthansa.  So in this specific case it may come down to the fine details of the interline agreement between Condor and Lufthansa.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Not exactly. See edit

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I see... it seems then that agreements are very very specific, even discriminating destination by destination, not only countries :(

Comment: Canadian transit visas are [free of charge](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/about-transit-visa.html).

Comment: @phoog If they are a Schengen state citizen, they 99% are eligible for an eTA, which eliminates the need of a full visa

Comment: @phoog eTA is 7$CAD

Comment: @Miguel yes, but a transit visa is free.  I suppose the greater convenience of eTA is well worth $7, however.